# How to align three widgets in an hboxlayout so that the first starts on the left, the second in the middle and the third on the right?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm implementing a search engine with widgets for filtering on the left and a dynamic display of the results in the middle. The display is nested as follows:

1. QScrollArea

   2. QWidget
      2.1 QVBoxLayout
   3. QWidget (Each result is a QWidget placed in the VBoxLayout)

A result Widget is organized in an HBoxlayout consisting of three Parts:

QLabel - QVBoxLayout - QVBoxlayout

I want the label to be aligned in the center, the first VBLayout to be aligned in the middle and the second Layout to be aligned right.

Code:
1. cpp:

```
QWidget* BildSuch_ErgWgt = new QWidget();
QVBoxLayout* BildSuch_Ergebnisleiste = new QVBoxLayout();
BildSuch_ErgWgt->setLayout(BildSuch_Ergebnisleiste); 
//I place Results dynamically in this layout

BildSuch_Ergebnisleiste->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize);     
//Does this affect the second Layout?

QScrollArea* BildSuch_ErgLeiSA = new QScrollArea();
...
BildSuch_ErgLeiSA->setWidget(BildSuch_ErgWgt);
```

The second class places the results found in the layout. 2. cpp:

```
QWidget* ErgWgt = new QWidget(); //This is a single result
QHBoxLayout* ErgWgtLay = new QHBoxLayout(); //The horizontal Layout for a single result

QLabel* ErgWgt_LblMinibild = new QLabel();
QPixmap* ErgWgt_Minibild = new QPixmap(Bilder.at(i)->getPfad());
ErgWgt_LblMinibild->setPixmap(ErgWgt_Minibild->scaled(250,250,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));

QVBoxLayout* ErgWgt_DatenLay = new QVBoxLayout(); //VBoxLayout filled with some Labels
...
QVBoxLayout* ErgWgt_BtnLay = new QVBoxLayout(); //VBoxLayout for Controls

ErgWgtLay->addWidget(ErgWgt_LblMinibild);
ErgWgtLay->addLayout(ErgWgt_DatenLay);
ErgWgtLay->addLayout(ErgWgt_BtnLay);

ErgWgt->setLayout(ErgWgtLay);

Stack->widget(3)->findChild<QVBoxLayout*>("BildSuch_Ergebnisleiste")->addWidget(ErgWgt); //Here i actualize the Results in the first Layout inside the ScrollArea
```

So, how to do that? I've tried a lot with stretch factors, spaceritems and stuff but except for hard coded px values nothing works. Perhaps because it's nested a little bit too complicated?

Thanks, Sebastian

Edit: A Screenshot will follow short:

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNN7i.jpg)

Comment: How did you add a stretch when it did not work? Did you do `ErgWgtLay->addStretch(1)` between `addWidget(ErgWgt_LblMinibild)` and `addLayout(ErgWgt_DatenLay)` lines?

Comment: No, when I used stretch I tried the following:                    `ErgWgtLay->setStretchFactor(ErgWgt_LblMinibild,2); 
ErgWgtLay->setStretchFactor(ErgWgt_DatenLay,2);
ErgWgtLay->setStretchFactor(ErgWgt_BtnLay,2);
ErgWgtLay->insertStretch(1,2);
ErgWgtLay->insertStretch(3,2);` This did not affect the output.

Comment: Seems legit, but I would guess that somehow `ErgwgtLay` might not take the whole width of the parent, that is why there is not stretching there. It is something like anchored to the top-right corner of the parent and do not fill all it is width. One of the steps is trying to remove this ` BildSuch_Ergebnisleiste->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize)`, to have `SetDefaultConstraint` that allows the layout to fill the parent, probably. Sorry for the heuristic here, I unfortunately do not have a minimal example that I can reproduce the case.